# Can I pass an element id in a css url call?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a svg file with a series of `<symbol>` s that all have unique ids. What I want to do is set the background-image property of an element in an html file as whatever id I pick like so

```
background-image: url(“sprite.svg#symbol_1”);
```

That path syntax works as “src” in an `<img>` or as “href” in a `<use>` , but I can’t seem to get it in css. If I put the symbols in a `<defs>` container, then set a `<use>` in the svg file, then the symbol I set the `<use>` to will display when I remove the “#symbol_1” but I then I can’t change it.

Comment: Javascript using data attibutes?

Comment: I understand that you are trying to use an svg <symbol> as a background image. It won't work. Symbols are not visible. Replace the symbols with nested svg elements or with groups. Please read more about [How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Comment: @dalelandry Yeah, I've been using a script to handle it so far, but I was trying to streamline it and make the process a little clearer and faster than javascript.

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks! That's actually super helpful. I feel kinda dumb now digging into mdn and csswg docs and not even thinking to look into <symbols> and how exactly they work.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this to work little while ago. Thanks in part to the link @enxaneta commented. That link essentially explains how to do it, but I'll give the quick version. In the svg file, if you add a style block like this:

```
<style>
  g {display: none;}
  g:target {display: inline;}
</style>
```

Then given that the images in your svg all fit in the same viewport, all you need to do is group the parts for each individual image (paths, shapes, etc) give the group an id and set the root svg element to the viewport size. Then the id reference for the group will be what you get in your css.

The hardest part was probably getting all the images to fit a single viewport since inkscape seems to kinda randomly make path commands relative or absolute, but while I was essentially remaking the whole thing; I was able to convert all the paths to "d" values for path classes in the style block and get rid of any transforms and that cut down the file size by like 40%.